# c# socket continuously messaging

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, timer, tcp-keepalive

I am struggling  for some days with this problem.
I have a server machine and I need to implement a client  .
Firstly I am sending a logon message and I am receiving the response.
After , I will need to send and receive different messages. 
From 10 to 10 seconds I need to send a "heartbeat message" , so the server needs to know that the connexion is still active.
I have made it a simple asynchronous client.

```
 private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {

      byte[] byteData = charTobyte(data.ToCharArray());
      client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
                sendDone.Set();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + " " + e.Message);
            }
        }


     private static void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the state object.  
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;

                // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;


                // Read data from the remote device.  
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {

                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));


                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                       response = state.sb.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
                    }
                    receiveDone.Set();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + " " + e.Message);
            }
        }


 private static void Heartbeat(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, Socket client)
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat...sent");
                SendHeart(client, DPLHeader(HeartBeat));
                sendHeart.WaitOne();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value: " + client.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive) + " : " + client.Connected);

            }

        }
```

This is what I am doing in the StartClient():

```
public static void StartClient()
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.  
            try
            {


                client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);


                // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                timer.Interval = 10000;
                timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((source, e) => Heartbeat(source, e, client));
                timer.Enabled = false;
                timer.AutoReset = false;

                timer.Start();

                message = DPLHeader(Messages.ElementAt(j));

                Send(client, message);
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                Console.WriteLine("value: " + client.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive) + " : " + client.Connected);



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + " " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The SendHeart() is just as a normal Send , just is sending the keepalive message.

The problem that I am facing is the next:
After the timer is firstly consumed and it triggers the Heartbeat() the appplication is only sending just the keepallive message, so it doesn t send the others messages . If it's sending just the keepallive message the connection is maintaining alive. Like the client can t access anymore the Send callback, and it remains just for the Heartbeat.

In another case I have made 3 timers , one for Send(),one for Receive(), and one for Heartbeat(). In this order and when one timer is expired it stops and starts the next one and so on. I send a message , I read a response and send a Heartbeat , after that any move I try to do BeginSend a message or BeginReceive a message , the connection is aborted by the host machine.

For the second case , another problem would be that if after sending a message, and starts the Receive, if the Heartbeat is sent the receive thread is lost so I can t read the message anymore.

Sorry if it's too tangled.
I am waiting for questions if you didn't understood something.
Thanks

Comment: What "others messages" are you sending? The only time `Send()` is called is directly after connection, sending `DPLHeader(Messages.ElementAt(j));`.

Comment: Different messages, "Status request", "Time request","Set_Time" for example. In the code I have writed here , yes it's called just one time. For the case where I have 3 timers for Send, Heart and Receive the trigger themselves . And for the first case I have tried to Call Send() at the end of the Receive() method.